# after_create doesn't have access to associated records created during before_created callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I am running into a weird issue, and reading the callbacks RoR guide didn't provide me an answer.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
has_many :company_users, dependent: :destroy
has_many :companies, through: :company_users
has_many :user_teams, dependent: :destroy
has_many :teams, through: :user_teams

before_create :check_company!
after_create :check_team

def check_company!
  return if self.companies.present?
  domain = self.email_domain
  company = Company.find_using_domain(domain)
  if company.present?
    assign_company(company)
  else
    create_and_assign_company(domain)
  end
end 

def check_team
  self.companies.each do |company|
    #do stuff
  end
end
...
end
```

The after_create :check_team callback is facing issues because the line

```
self.companies.each do |company|
```

Here, self.companies is returning an empty array [] even though the Company and User were created and the User was associated with it. I know I can solve it by making it a before_create callback instead. But I am puzzled!

Why does the after_create callback not have access to self's associations  after the commit?

Solution: Please read my comments in the accepted answer to see the cause of the problem and the solution.

Comment: is associated model `company` already saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- inside `before_create` callbacks, the `id` of the record is not yet available, because it is before... create... So it is not yet persisting in the database to have an `id`. This means that the associated `company_user` record doesn't have a `user_id` value yet, precisely because the `user.id` is still `nil` at that point. However, Rails makes this easy for you to not worry about this "chicken-and-egg" problem, provided that you do it correctly:
- I recreated your setup (`Company`, `User`, and `CompanyUser` models), and the following is what should work on your case (tested working):

  ```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :company_users, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :companies, through: :company_users

    before_create :check_company!
    after_create :check_team

    def check_company!
      # use `exists?` instead of `present?` because `exists?` is a lot faster and efficient as it generates with a `LIMIT 1` SQL.
      return if companies.exists?

      ## when assigning an already persisted Company record:
      example_company = Company.first
      # 1) WORKS
      companies << example_company
      # 2) WORKS
      company_users.build(company: example_company)

      ## when assigning and creating a new Company record:
      # 1) WORKS (this company record will be automatically saved/created after this user record is saved in the DB)
      companies.build(name: 'ahaasdfwer') # or... self.companies.new(name: 'ahaasdfwer')
      # 2) DOES NOT WORK, because you'll receive an error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: You cannot call create unless the parent is saved`
      companies.create(name: 'ahaasdfwer')
    end

    def check_team
      puts companies.count
      # => 1 if "worked"
      puts companies.first.persisted?
      # => true if "worked"
    end
  end
  ```

Comment: If this still doesn't work, can you update your question and include the code where you are "assigning" or "creating" the Company record? In particular, it would be whatever code you have for `assign_company(company)` and `create_and_assign_company(domain)`

Comment: Thanks for giving me the idea that finally resolved the problem. Basically, using a `self.reload` as the first line in the :check_team function.

Comment: Glad to help :) Yes `self.reload` will work if you have a code that would have already preloaded the associated `companies`, perhaps you have it in `assign_company` or `create_and_assign_company`? Normally otherwise, you won't need to `self.reload` the record. But, it's good that it already worked! ^-^

Comment: Thanks for giving me the idea that finally resolved the problem. Basically, using a `self.reload` as the first line in the :check_team function.

To see it in action yourself, you can do as follows:
`u=User.first`
`c=Company.first`
`u.company_users.build(company: c)`
`u.save`
`u.companies`
#It will return an empty array!

Whereas if you do
`u.companies << c`
It obviously works.

This isn't the first time the needing to reload in order to update associations has bitten me the first time. But I believe this time, I learned something new instead of just fixing something :)

Comment: I just tried what you wrote in Rails console: `u=User.first \n c=Company.first 
\n u.company_users.build(company: c) \n u.save \n u.companies`. However, I got a different result: it returned company records and not empty. What Rails version are you currently using? I tested these scenarios in Rails 5.

Comment: But regardless if it already worked for you then that's good! :) Although if you have time and curious as to why we got different results, just let me know anytime :)

Comment: I am also using Rails 5 (with Ruby v2.4). I tried it again and it is still giving me the same result. This is definitely a curious scenario.

Comment: Perhaps you have some `after_save` or `before_save` callbacks in `User` model that would have cleared off the associated `companies` records? Or maybe there was some validation error? Try `u.company_users.create!(company: c)` instead of `u.company_users.build(company: c)`, and see if it raises an error. Unfortunately, I tried but I couldn't recreate your exact scenario.

Comment: Same result for me even with create! I don't see any callbacks beyond the two already mentioned here. My app is an API only app and uses Devise. Anyway, I give up. Maybe we can open a new question and ask why this is happening and what is the default expected behaviour :)